# How an automation script of 100 test cases should be written using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

Kindly explain whether I should write only 1 java file for all the test cases or individual java file for single test case

Comment: this could help https://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/selenium-best-practices/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I am not much clear about it.  Lets take an example, I have test cases like login, Create customer and verify it, create an account and verify, Edit customer details and verify, Edit Account details and verify etc... So how should I write script... Should I write a single java file of all the test cases which will be quite complicated or should I write a single java file for just 1 test case...

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough details to give a specific answer, so I try to put down some guiding principles. Those principles are just software design 101, so you might want to do some learning and reading in that direction.

The key question really is: how similar are your tests.

**they vary just in the values**

You really have just one test, that you put in a loop in order to iterate through all the values. Note that also a behavior can be a value. In this case you could use the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

**they are variations of the same test idea**
You probably want some classes representing the elements of the tests, which then get combined into tests. For example elements might be TestSteps, which then get combined into tests. If the combining is really simple. It might be feasible to put it all in one class, but with 100 tests, that is unlikely.

**completely independent tests**

You are probably better of to put them in different classes/files. But you probably still find lots of stuff to reuse (for example [PageObjects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)) which should go into separate classes.

In the end I would expect for 100 tests maybe 50 classes: Many test classes, containing 1-20 tests each, that have a lot of stuff they share, plus a healthy does of classes that encapsulate common functionality (PageObjects, Matcher, predefined TestSteps and so on)

Answer (score -1):

According to one [source](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/37-oop) you should used one class per test, but to used inheritance of classes:

> Think of each class as a test case, and focus it on a particular aspect (or component) of the system you're testing. This provides an easy way to add new test cases (simply create a new class) and modify and update existing tests (by removing/disabling test methods within a class). It can greatly help organize your test suites by allowing existing tests (e.g., individual methods) to be easily combined together.

Comment: recommending/using inheritance is really a bad idea in the general case.